# My sqLite cursor is running over the end of the loop and generating a CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I have populated a sqLite database under Android with 561 records.. 

and now I'm trying to log them to the Log.. The cursor appears to be running off the end..

I've broken it down and added in start and breakpoints but it drops off the end... 
Google is great for cursors with 0 records..

```
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("INSERT INTO product (barcode, description, brand) VALUES ('20675578','smoked back bacon - 8 rashers','warren & sons')");
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("INSERT INTO product (barcode, description, brand) VALUES ('5010431600941','Meatballs','ye olde oak')");
        Log.i("UserResults - name", "Point 3");

        // List the products
        Cursor c = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM product", null);
        int barcodeIndex = c.getColumnIndex("barcode");
        int descriptionIndex = c.getColumnIndex("description");
        int brandIndex = c.getColumnIndex("brand");

        c.moveToFirst();
        while (c != null) {
            String textString = "Product - [" + c.getString(barcodeIndex) + "]["+ c.getString(descriptionIndex)+ "][" + c.getString(brandIndex) + "]";
            Log.i("SQL-Log", textString );
            c.moveToNext();
        }
        c.close();
```

I expect it top move onto the next section which is to load records into a different table.. but I'm getting this:

```
019-05-19 16:05:29.102 3402-3402/com.example.food001 I/SQL-Log: Product - [20675578][smoked back bacon - 8 rashers][warren & sons]
2019-05-19 16:05:29.102 3402-3402/com.example.food001 I/SQL-Log: Product - [5010431600941][Meatballs][ye olde oak]  <---Good so far!
2019-05-19 16:05:29.104 3402-3402/com.example.food001 W/System.err: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 561 requested, with a size of 561
2019-05-19 16:05:29.105 3402-3402/com.example.food001 W/System.err:     at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:468)
2019-05-19 16:05:29.105 3402-3402/com.example.food001 W/System.err:     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
2019-05-19 16:05:29.106 3402-3402/com.example.food001 W/System.err:     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:50)
2019-05-19 16:05:29.106 3402-3402/com.example.food001 W/System.err:     at com.example.food001.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:1207)
2019-05-19 16:05:29.106 3402-3402/com.example.food001 W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7441)
2019-05-19 16:05:29.107 3402-3402/com.example.food001 W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7431)
2019-05-19 16:05:29.107 3402-3402/com.example.food001 W/System.err:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1286)
2019-05-19 16:05:29.107 3402-3402/com.example.food001 W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3343)
2019-05-19 16:05:29.107 3402-3402/com.example.food001 W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3548)
2019-05-19 16:05:29.107 3402-3402/com.example.food001 W/System.err:     at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:86)
2019-05-19 16:05:29.108 3402-3402/com.example.food001 W/System.err:     at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
2019-05-19 16:05:29.108 3402-3402/com.example.food001 W/System.err:     at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
2019-05-19 16:05:29.108 3402-3402/com.example.food001 W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2155)
2019-05-19 16:05:29.108 3402-3402/com.example.food001 W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:109)
2019-05-19 16:05:29.108 3402-3402/com.example.food001 W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
2019-05-19 16:05:29.108 3402-3402/com.example.food001 W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7539)
2019-05-19 16:05:29.109 3402-3402/com.example.food001 W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
2019-05-19 16:05:29.109 3402-3402/com.example.food001 W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:524)
2019-05-19 16:05:29.110 3402-3402/com.example.food001 W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:958)
2019-05-19 16:05:29.117 3402-3402/com.example.food001 D/ActivityThread: add activity client record, r= ActivityRecord{a45a309 token=android.os.BinderProxy@7cb25b0 {com.example.food001/com.example.food001.MainActivity}} token= android.os.BinderProxy@7cb25b0
2019-05-19 16:05:29.132 3402-3402/com.example.food001 D/ZrHung.AppEyeUiProbe: notify runnable to start.
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
  Log.i("UserResults - name", "Point 3");

    // List the products
    Cursor c = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM product", null);
    int barcodeIndex = c.getColumnIndex("barcode");
    int descriptionIndex = c.getColumnIndex("description");
    int brandIndex = c.getColumnIndex("brand");

     if (c.moveToFirst()){
   do{
       String textString = "Product - [" + c.getString(barcodeIndex) + "]["+ c.getString(descriptionIndex)+ "][" + c.getString(brandIndex) + "]";
            Log.i("SQL-Log", textString );
   }while(c.moveToNext());
}
    c.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

The method `rawQuery()` will not return a null object, be sure for that.
So you only need to check if the cursor contains any rows and since the cursor's position at the beginning is before the 1st row (if there is a row), then you only need to check the condition `moveToNext()`.
So drop `c.moveToFirst();` and do this:

```
while (c.moveToNext()) {
    String textString = "Product - [" + c.getString(barcodeIndex) + "]["+ c.getString(descriptionIndex)+ "][" + c.getString(brandIndex) + "]";
    Log.i("SQL-Log", textString );
}
```